# Getting a list of supported font formats through the terminal

Tags: command-line, fonts

I would like to know what version of OpenType and TrueType my Ubuntu system supports.

And if Ubuntu supports other types of font standards is there a way to get a list and the versions through the terminal?

Comment: I played around a bit with [the fontconfig library](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) and its command-line tools like [`fc-list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/fc-list.1.html), but the best I came up with is a list of the currently installed font files' extensions: `fc-list|sed 's/.*\.\(\w*\):.*/\1/'|sort -u` – This doesn't really answer your question, or does it?

Comment: [Arch Linux Wiki's Font configuration article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration) might also be helpful.

Comment: @dessert nop. I knew already about fc-list. I am looking for the version support for OpenType, TrueType, etc.

Comment: @dessert you might be onto something with your second comment.